# Music player for Windows that supports many themes

Tags: windows, music

I need a music player for Windows OS that supports many themes.

Currently I use Windows Media Player as my music player, but I got bored with it. So suggest me a good music player that can be customized with themes.

Requirements:

- Play mp3, wav, ogg at least
- Free
- More than 100 available themes

Comment: How is over 100 available themes an important feature? You just need *one* ;p

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com) is a "god" music player, but definitly it's a good music player ;)
Beside of a large number of default color themes it also has a huge load of [custom themes](http://www.allwinampskins.com)

Another option would be the [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org). I haven't used this media player yet, but as far as i know its high customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have searched many music player for a free, powerful and customizable one (from foobar to zune to many others) and finally found a near perfect music player for my needs:

[**MusicBee**](http://getmusicbee.com/)

IMO, it's near perfect. It's strong in playback, has great song info editing capabilities (+ folder/file managing). In terms of customization, it has many skins to choose from and you can also change many UI parts like fonts,...